# MPMoviePlayerController - black screen when switching views

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

The background image is an animated sky

When switching between settings page (static image) and the home page (animated image) the screen animation often drops off and becomes a single black image

Can anybody suggest a reason or a solution?

Thanks!

Henry Colour Vision Apps

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iPhone4" ofType:@"mov"]]];
    mp.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    [mp.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    mp.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [mp setFullscreen:YES];
    mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:mp.view];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:mp.view];
    [mp prepareToPlay];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.mp play];
}
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot or some more details of switching

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jg7169bc5ron3qp/BLACK%20SCREEN%20iP5.PNG

Comment: i added the photo link via dropbox. Thanks. Henry

Comment: you are sending subview to back . Instead of sending subview to back use bringsubview to front what view you want to display.

Comment: the animation is displayed in the background so that other elements are not obscured

Comment: see screenshot website www.daydreamalarm.com

Comment: Where are you playing animations??

Answer (score 0):

Try add a observer to your player. Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ///...
    self.mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iPhone4" ofType:@"mov"]]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                              name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                            object:self.mp];
     ///...
}
```

Then you can get what's wrong:

```
- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   NSLog(@"Movie Finished.");

   int reason = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];
   if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError) {
      NSDictionary *notificationUserInfo = [notification userInfo];
      NSError *mediaPlayerError = [notificationUserInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
      if (mediaPlayerError)
      {
         NSLog(@"playback failed with error description: %@", [mediaPlayerError localizedDescription]);
      }
      else
      {
         NSLog(@"playback failed without any given reason");
      }
   }    

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.mp];
```

}